# Need to set a breakpoint when `style.top` is altered for one specific element id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

## Something is altering `.top` and `.left` and I need to track down the guilty function.

I am using several large JavaScript libraries to which I DO have access.

One of these libraries is moving an HTML element very far off-screen by adjusting the `top` and `left` values in the `<style>` attribute of the HTML element.

I am happy to use any debugger (Safari, Chrome, Firefox).  Can I set a breakpoint or a watch or SOMETHING to help me locate where these two values are erroneously being set?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If it's not too much to change (or maybe only apply to a few styles to check), but append extra text to the style being altered to something else such as cssMine, or whatever, to see if it avoids getting altered. If it doesn't, then one of the libraries must be using the same named style. Then it would only be a matter of using a new name. (hope this makes sense)